# Retain activation value of relay block in Simulink

Tags: simulink

Once a relay block is turned on, it stays on and outputs the current input value. However, I want the input value that originally activated the relay block to continue being the output value (i.e. override the current input value). Thus, the output from the relay block only changes when 1) the relay is switched off or 2) the relay is switched back on according to the specified threshold. Any thoughts on how to do this? Below is my Simulink model (tracking volume of water in a tank and activating a pump to discharge the water when the volume hits a threshhold); my question pertains to the first relay block.
[image: simulinkmodel]

Answer (score 1):

The Relay block outputs the value(s) specified in the block's dialog not the current value of the input.  You can achieve what (I think) you're asking by setting the Switch On/Off value to be the same as the Output when On/Off value.